# How to verify if my text contains a word using regex and C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to verify if my text contains a String that starts with 3 char `[a-zA-Z]` (CRM) and after this 3 char it contains 9 numbers `[0-9]` 
like this "CRM123456789"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
bool valid = Regex.IsMatch(input,@"^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{9}$");
```

Comment: Doesn't check if it starts with `CRM`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter he gave `CRM` as an example.

Comment: @TimSchmelter @"^CRM[0-9]{9}$" in this case but he/she posted allready part of the regex so i thought i stick to that

Answer (score 4):

Use anchors in-order to do an exact string match. `^` asserts that we are the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{9}$
```

`{num}`   repeatation quantifier which repeats the previous token according to the number present inside curly braces. So `{9}` in this `[0-9]{9}` pattern would repeat the previous token `[0-9]` exactly 9 times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lL9lB4/8)

Comment: You're just to quick when it comes to regex!

Comment: Hehe thats what i thought =)

Comment: @abdelazizmaroc Accept anyone of the answers from here which helps you the most.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for that task:

```
bool valid = input.Length == 12 
          && input.StartsWith("CRM") 
          && input.Substring(3).All(Char.IsDigit);
```

If `CRM` was only an example and all letters are allowed as first three characters:

```
bool valid = input.Length == 12 
          && input.Remove(3).All(Char.IsLetter) 
          && input.Substring(3).All(Char.IsDigit);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "CRM123456789" appears in some longer text, you'd need to check the boundaries that work for you. In my case, there are often words next to punctuation marks, or spaces. I'd use:

`(?<=^|\p{P}|\p{Zs}|\b)[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{9}(?=$|\p{P}|\p{Zs}|\b)`

See [demo here](https://www.myregextester.com/?r=78eba81f).

Comment: @abdelazizmaroc: You are welcome. Next time please provide more context your matches appear in. This will decrease the number of "extra" answers :) As, perhaps, mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using linq:

```
if(input.Length == 12) // check characters are 12
{
 if(input.Take(3).All(x=> Char.IsLetter(x)) // First 3 are alphabets
 && input.Skip(3).All(x=>Char.IsDigit(x))) // next all numbers
   return true;
 else
  return false;

}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class TestRegularExpressionValidation
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] listofinputs = 
        {
            "CRM32323324", 
            "232dsf12414", 
            "adfn adfm srf333333333 sdj",
            "srf333333333",
            "saca dfd444444444r.",
            "CRM876969697", 
        };

        string sPattern = "^\\w{3}\\d{9}$";

        foreach (string s in listofinputs)
        {
            System.Console.Write("{0,14}", s);

            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, sPattern))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(" - valid");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(" - invalid");
            }
        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any additional explanation (or pointing out the most important parts) would make your answer even better.  Code-only answers can sometimes be hard to understand.